# Should members of the forum be able to delete answers in a topic that is outside of their field?

Tags: feature-request, deletion

I the following thread in the field "algebraic geometry"

[Why isn't every finite locally free morphism etale?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3952067/why-isnt-every-finite-locally-free-morphism-etale/3957404#3957404)

an answer to a question was deleted by two people that are not doing algebraic geometry. Should members of the forum be able to delete answers in a topic that is outside of their field?

Comment: The user admits in a post that he has no knowledge about the field.

Comment: Alright i am talking in general, how do you think  the rules can be changed, i mean there is no definite way  to know whether someone is well versed in a field or not ,is there?(of course  other than looking at their top tags which may not always be helpful)

Comment: This forum will become a big joke if a person posting answers and questions in one field is able to delete questions and answers in another field. In order to be alowed to delete a question or answer in a field you need to have posted accepted answers in that field. I suggest the owners of this forum change the rules for this reason - in the above thread one of the persons voting to delete the post has not posted any answers in the field and it is quite clear this person has limited knowledge in algebraic geometry.

Comment: The company that own and runs this site has the following "vision": Empower people to deliver outstanding results. Give people space to get their job done, support them when they need it, and practice blameless accountability.  Be flexible and inclusive. We do our best work when a diverse group of people collaborate in an environment of respect and trust. Create space for different voices to be heard, and allow flexibility in how people work.

Comment: More "vision": Learn, share, grow. Adopt a Growth Mindset. Be curious and eager to learn. Aim for ethical, sustainable, long-term growth, both personally and in the company.  Be transparent. Communicate openly and honestly, both inside and outside the company. Encourage transparency from others by being empathetic, reliable, and acting with integrity.

Comment: It should be mentioned that the reason given in the comments for the deletion of your answer was not mathematical at all. You already have an answer there, which you can freely edit to include the other answer. I don't understand algebraic geometry so I can't tell if the answers are distinct enough to merit a second answer

Comment: This is the point; The person that was involved in deleting the answer does not know either - it is not his field and he does not have the knowledge to decide if the answer is "distinct enough".

Comment: that said, these comments of his were upvoted 2 times. These could be votes by people who clicked naturally on the question, or maybe not? And this now-deleted answer has a negative score

Comment: This is the problem with this site - the people that upvote/downvote are anonymous.

Comment: Actually, your answer doesn't seem to stand alone, precisely because you claim upfront that it is a continuation of the other answer. If it was an e.g. alternative proof, then there could be merit to a second answer

Comment: if you have trouble combining the two answers, I can copy the contents of the second into the first?

Comment: Company "vision": Be transparent. Communicate openly and honestly, both inside and outside the company. Encourage transparency from others by being empathetic, reliable, and acting with integrity. If this site wants to be transparent, the "upvote/downvote" should be open and the identity of the people voting should be "transparent".

Comment: Thanks for the offer of assistance. A problem with this site is that some users have computers that are "slow" and where writing answers with more than 3500 characters is impossible.   For such users writing several "answers" on the same topic is necessary.

Comment: This web site is one of the products/services of the company. Their guidelines for the company structure don't automatically apply within these forums. Additionally, this is not a peer-review site staffed by paid professionals, it is a collection of volunteers at all levels of who enjoy and build an on-line community. One key difference this makes is that if someone is brilliant but doesn't get along well with others they're probably going to be dissatisfied here.

Comment: This does not have so much to do with "getting along with others" - the site is about answering questions posed by PhD students. It is not about "winning the race to be the first person to answer a question". If others interfere in this process this communication with a person asking a question is destroyed. If the site owners introduce an additional restriction ensuring that people cannot delete posts that are not in their field this will increase the quality of the site....

Comment: And students will ask more questions since they get answers by people that are working in the field - without interference from others.

Comment: Since you asked if that user is a moderator, I am a moderator. **This is not a forum**. It's a Q&A website. If you want to have a continuation of an answer, *edit that answer*. Do not post a new one.

Comment: I still think the owners of the site should change the rules - this is a Q&A site where you "rank" people and give people "privileges" to improve the quality of the posts, and to let people without knowledge on a topic delete a discussion on that topic seems to go against this philosophy.

Comment: If you take a look at some of the comments on the  deleted post you will find that this "winning the race to be the first person to answer a question" is wrecking the site. PhD students fear asking questions - they are afraid of being accused of being stupid or asking stupid questions. I'm sure this is not the intention of this Q&A site?

Comment: Here is an example: "That's MO, which isn't this site and frequently does things a little differently (not that you should take "no negative feedback" as evidence that what you're doing is completely fine, though). I'm not a moderator, I'm just letting you know what's generally accepted behavior around here since you appear to be new." If I was a PhD student, this type of post might scare me off the site. Is this what the owner of this site wants?

Comment: You seem very confused.  This site is not just for PhD students; it's for anyone who wants to ask a mathematical question (and is willing to read the guidelines on how to ask a good question and follow them), and for people who can provide good answers to those questions.  The "owner" of the site is ostensibly Stack Overflow, but practically the community here.  You seem intent on ignoring responses from the "owner" (the community) though and pushing your own agenda only.

Comment: "the site is about answering questions posed by PhD students". You've been a member 18 days.

Comment: Not to touch the main discussion here, but when I want to draft an especially long answer, I sometimes write it in a TeX editor locally on my computer (or any text editor, really) and then copy it into the site, which usually avoids any trouble with the site running slow. There's also the [sandbox for long posts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-posts) on meta, which can be useful - although I'm not sure whether this is a solution to your particular problem, but it's something to be aware of - some users find it helpful.

Comment: To Karaglia: "That's MO, which isn't this site and frequently does things a little differently (not that you should take "no negative feedback" as evidence that what you're doing is completely fine, though). I'm not a moderator, I'm just letting you know what's generally accepted behavior around here since you appear to be new." You have an impressive CV. Would you give this type of response to a PhD student that does not have a long and impressive CV?

Comment: Asaf would give (and has given) that response to anyone misunderstanding math.se a profoundly as you, regardless of level or achievement -- which you seem to be massively hung up on.

Comment: I am one of the users who voted to delete your answer. You are right: the topic of this post is outside my fields of expertise. But my reason for voting this way had nothing to do with its mathematical content. It was because your post was the continuation of your previous post. If you have an answer, you should give it in a single post.

Comment: I joined this site in the months between my B.Sc. and my M.Sc., so I did not have any CV to begin with. I'm glad that you think my work in this decade is impressive. But it wasn't always like that. I spent the first couple of weeks on this site mostly observing the site before posting anything substantial; I spent the first few months mostly observing on meta, and only formed actual opinions after that. I did not start by presuming that I understand the site, its culture, and jumped to defend my opinions. And back then the site was a week old. So yes, I'd give that response to anyone.

Comment: Just as a side note (since you wrote "To Karagila"), you are displaying another lack of understanding how this site work. Read about [comment replies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) with the link in the [help centre](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). This community can be a great tool for improving your maths, your teaching skills, and yourself. But you need to understand how it works before passing judgement on how it works.

Comment: @José maybe you could tell us why you haven't copied OP's now-deleted second answer, and pasted it into OP's first answer? That would seem to take care of objections to deleted content.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I felt that it would be more natural that it would be the OP to do that.

Comment: @José OK, so, you left OP a comment to suggest OP do that?

Comment: @GerryMyerson the OP had been engaged in comments right at the start of the process, specifically they had been told "If this is a continuation of your other post, it should be a part of that other post. Multiple answers are [generally discouraged](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10205/multiple-answers) outside of some special cases, none of which apply here. Note that you aren't even close to the character limit for a single post (these two posts combined are ~6500 characters, the limit is 30,000)."

Comment: It has been brought up that it can be technically complicated to edit longer posts. This is a valid concern. Indeed there is a dedicated thread on meat that can be used as "sandbox" for just that https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-posts

Comment: "maybe you could tell us why you haven't copied OP's now-deleted second answer, and pasted it into OP's first answer" Does the OP have access to the text of their deleted answer? (I don't know if that is affected by rep level or self vs. other deletion.) If they do, I strongly suggest leaving that as something for the OP to do. (cont'd)....

Comment: ... (cont'd) Because one of the hardest parts about interacting with others here is knowing when it has become pointless, versus it being worth a bit more patience and interaction. The OP has been told exactly what needs to be done; if they can't do that then this question can be closed.

Answer (score 13):

**Yes**, and your example shows why.

Most deletions of answers are not motivated by the mathematical content of the post, yet instead by formal reasons, e.g., the answer-post is asks a new question, and thus should be a new question-post or maybe a comment; the answer-post tries to engage with other users, and should be a comment, instead; the answer-post continues an earlier post and should be an edit to the earlier post.

The last one is your case.

To decide this, no in-depth mathematical knowledge is needed. It is a formal check and can be carried out by a much broader group of users. To insist that it must only by done by experts in the field misses the point.

By analogy, if I, as instructor of a course, insist that the students hand in sheets with assigned homework only in an envelope that indicates their name and the course, and that they deposit it in the office of an administrative assistant, then it is reasonable for that administrative assistant to refuse loose sheets. To explain to them that they must not refuse the homework because it is perfectly correct and they are not qualified to judge this, simply misses the point.

Arguably it is overly rigid or even pointless to insist on the sheets being in an envelope, but that's neither here nor there, and in particular it is completely inappropriate to target the administrative assistant about it because they did not make that rule either.

To come back to the present situation, if you want to discuss the merits of insisting on an edit rather than a second post, then you should ask about that, not question the qualifications of those that correctly enforced an established rule.

Comment: The "rules" you refer to are not written down anywhere, and are decided by a group of "trusted" users. If you want this site to be a site where eveybody - amateurs, high school students and Phd/Msc students ask questions, you should at least inform new users about these "unwritten rules", and try to do this in a way that does not "scare" students. In this case it seems that to use several posts....

Comment: ...to formulate an answer is "generally discouraged" - it is not a "strict rule". This was one of the reasons I chose to write this question. It was not clear to me if this "deletion" was about "intimidation" or if it was an explicit rule of this Q&A site.

Comment: "I am one of the users who voted to delete your answer. You are right: the topic of this post is outside my fields of expertise. But my reason for voting this way had nothing to do with its mathematical content. It was because your post was the continuation of your previous post. If you have an answer, you should give it in a single post." Reply: It was my impression that it was "generally discouraged" to write several posts on one answer. When you deleted the post you did not give any reason for this deletion and this was why I wrote this question.

Comment: "If this is a continuation of your other post, it should be a part of that other post. Multiple answers are generally discouraged outside of some special cases, none of which apply here. Note that you aren't even close to the character limit for a single post (these two posts combined are ~6500 characters, the limit is 30,000)" Here a "trusted user" is referring to "some special cases" - what are these "special cases"?

Comment: @hm2020: *A lot* of your arguments can be *very* simply countered by "take a few days to learn the territory before you charge into battle". Nobody here is attacking you, but it seems like you're taking a lot of it personally. We've been there before, each and every one of us. But you're a new user in a website that is a decade old. If you think that we're doing it wrong, go ahead and start you own site. But otherwise, it might be worth moving on from this, you made a mistake, that happens, you were called out, learn from it, move on. That's how we grow in life.

Comment: @Asaf Karaglia: This is where you misunderstand - I did not "charge into battle". It was an honest question - I therefore pose this question to you since you are a "moderator": "What are these "special cases"" referred to in my previous post?

Comment: @hm2020 it is an explicit rule that that answer posts and question posts should be expanded by edits rather then be completed by a new post in the thread. It is so ingrained that it is even built-in the software. When you added the second answer didn't the site ask you "Are you sure you want to add another answer?

You could use the edit link to refine and improve your existing answer, instead." Further, as a moderator I even have a dedicated feature to deal with non-compliance, it is called "convert to edit."

Comment: @hm2020 a common "special case" is when completely independent answers are given. For example, a user could give an answer that avoids certain tools because they are not sure everybody is familiar with them and then also give an answer that uses these tools. We also have some questions that asks for examples of things, or for recommendations of  books, etc.  In such cases it can make sense to have one item per answer.

Comment: I truly believe the site would improve if the voting system was open and transparent, and where downvotes/upvotes was done in a transparent way. My argument is the same: A downvote of a question in one field A from someone that has no knowledge on A is worthless.

Comment: @hm2020: I am not a "moderator", I am a moderator. Special cases are, as quid suggested, when the answers are completely independent of each other, but even then if the answers are short enough, one might put them into a single answer and not two.See, for example, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10205/multiple-answers

Comment: @hm2020: Votes are not just about content. They are also about presentation and context. Next time when you have a lecture, try asking a very good question (better yet, about a different subject) while taking off your shirt, see what happens.

Comment: This thread was about the "unwritten rules" on this site, and again I believe the downvote/upvote system could be improved if the vote was open: What is the downvote about: Is it about content or is it about the "presentation"? If the voter has no knowledge on the field - make this clear and explain why you downvote. In this particular situation it was a downvote for other reasons: It was because of some "unwritten rules".

Comment: There are probably dozens of posts from previous years about whether or not downvotes should be (or must be) linked to the user, or have reasons given. Have you acquainted yourself with them, and do you know the current state of the arguments?

Comment: I did not find any such discussion during my search.