# Non-experts closing questions

Tags: discussion, tagging, closing, closed-questions

I have recently noticed what, to me, is a pretty irking trend in the tag I contribute to most often (algebraic geometry). It seems to me that there is a contingent of 'serial closers' who insist on closing questions despite those questions having (at least from my perspective) non-trivial academic merit. What bothers me the most is these 'serial closers' seemingly have zero knowledge about the threads they condemn—or, more accurately, essentially have never contributed to answering questions in the relevant tag.

Is it possible to restrict people's moderation abilities largely to certain pre-approved tags where, of course, pre-approval should be related to one's contribution to those tags? This is perhaps not tenable given the size of this website/nicheness of some tags, but I feel like something should be done.

**EDIT:** When I wrote the above(/the previous edits) I was frustrated, and consequently was fairly pompous and overly accusatory. I apologize for that. My main concern is for students who can't get their legitimate questions answered because of non-optimal procedures for closing questions. I hope that the tone of my question doesn't distract the reader from this.

Comment: Are these of the "problem-statement only, but interesting question" variety?

Comment: @MichaelJesurum Hey Michael. I'd like to link some examples, but given the public nature of who closed the questions, I think that'd be a bit inappropriate. That said, the examples I have in mind are not even homework-problem type questions (which is what 'problem-statement' makes me think). They are like "Here is a natural question that has arisen in my studies which I haven't been able to find an answer to. Can someone help?" Sometimes these closed questions are about topics that even knowledge contributors say they benefit from. I think it's possible that the closers think they lack context

Comment: (cont.) perhaps, but that's only (in my opinion) because they're non-experts--most of the questions I can think of (which cite "Please provide additional context..." as their reason for closing) are self-evidentally interesting/self-explanatory to anyone who is well-versed in that subject.

Comment: This reminded me of some post made by Jyrki Lahtonen, such as: [Is it appropriate to close every question that doesn't show efforts and/or lacks of context?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26429#26445) and [Why a question without showing any work is getting upvoted?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22415#22416) (Although he seems to have [changed his mind a bit](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/20352?m=56005138#56005138) since then.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Hey Martin. Thanks for the links--I'll check them out!

Comment: You don't need to be a parent to have a good advice on raising kids. You don't need to be a general to have a good advice on having war (don't, by the way). You can have something to say about the quality of the question as a non expert. Having said that, I do agree that some of the more advanced questions sometimes can be seen as having no context, where in fact anyone who can understand it anyway already knows the whole context. This is why closure is reversible and we can reopen stuff.

Comment: Your question starts off phrased as "people who aren't experts are unqualified to close a question of that topic" but actually you can only get as far as "people who aren't experts might not understand that a particular question in the topic is actually interesting." The main qualification for closing questions is being well-versed in the quality guidelines. That's the cause for most closures, I'd wager.

Comment: We all occasionally feel warm fuzzies for questions in fields near and dear to our hearts and which aren't very good quality, but we have to recognize that is personal bias speaking.  In such a case one can only see if you or the poster can make it palatable.

Comment: I'd just like to thow in that adding enough context that certain non-experts can appreciate the question is nice. It increases accessibility for future students browsing MSE who are learning that subject for the first time. I wouldn't advocate writing pages and pages of background, but I feel like setting the bar at "non-experts recognize that context is given" is not unreasonable.

Comment: @rschwieb I think you have mildly missed the point, or perhaps I didn't put a fine enough point on it. For example, often the close votes are (as mentioned above) "Please provide additional context..." This is such a wildly subjective criterion, especially when judged by non-experts.

Comment: (cont.) It's not about the interestingness of the question (most of them aren't necessarily interesting to me) but are very reasonable, well-posed questions to anyone putting a serious effort into studying the topic the tag pertains to. The question poster shouldn't given context for what fpqc descent is, because anyone who could answer that question/would be interested in that question already knows what it is. I have never in my 10+ years on this website pored over the 'quality guidelines', but I imagine that they are common sense things that all the posts I can think of certainly meet.

Comment: @AsafKaragila See my response to **rschweib**. The posts I can think of are not blatantly obvious examples of poor questions. Their closure is usually on some ambiguous grounds of something like 'not enough context'. And yes, we can reopen them, but it's a bit non-ideal that new users trying to seek to understand a question in their field of study need to be advocated for by people with reopening powers.

Comment: Yes, I agree, and I see that happening in the set theory tag sometimes. But frankly, I don't have a good solution to this problem. The best I can suggest is to leave a comment that you disagree with the closing votes and hope that will deter others from voting to close.

Comment: @AlexYoucis When you say "The question poster shouldn't given context for what fpqc descent is, because anyone who could answer that question/would be interested in that question already knows what it is." I think that is part of the disagreement. I think "There's enough context so that an expert understands it." is  not a good bar.

Comment: @MichaelJesurum Yes, I think that's fair. I think 'non-expert' was maybe a poor choice of terminology. The people who close these questions have seemingly never contributed a single answer to a tag even adjacent to the relative one. I don't mean 'non-expert' as in 'a first year graduate student familiar with the material', I mean 'someone who has never picked up a book on the topic'.

Comment: @rschwieb My impression of the goal of this website is not to serve as a live journal for people's mathematical thoughts, but a place to have specific questions answered. If I want to know why every finite-dimensional $k$-algebra is Artinian, I don't think it's reasonable/worthwhile to define what Artinian means, to explain where this has come up in one's studies, etc. These aspects of the question are self-evident to anyone who is likely to be interested in the question, let alone able to answer it. And, if not, they are free to google the relevant terms.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I do not think "a live journal for people's mathematical thoughts" is a representation of what I've suggested by any means.  What I do think is your suggestion to prohibit people from moderating is both too subjective and too exclusive.  As the last comment evidences, we are at cross purposes at this point. Time for some concrete examples.  I'm sure consensus can be reached on whether or not your examples are bad for quality standard reasons or have "magic expert interest" mojo that makes them worth keeping.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I think someone who has never picked up a book on the topic should still recognize some context. For instance, saying a few words about where the problem came from probably makes the question more searchable, which is always good. As someone who's never picked up a book on a wide range of topics, I'd like to think I could recognize if someone had a couple sentences of background. Still, I totally believe there could be examples where people didn't recognize exactly that.

Comment: @rschwieb I didn't mean to sound confrontational--my hyperbole came off more aggressive than I intended. The first example of a closed question in algebraic-geometry is an example. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4183836/proper-morphism-and-base-change

Comment: @AlexYoucis That's ok, you've reassured me, and thank you for doing so!

Comment: @AlexYoucis Hm, good example: I can see how that fell onto the faultline between enough/not enough context. But I am certain it was not closed because of something about the terms not being explained. Rather, it looks like the user has a question and much to show in the way of progress.  But in this case I agree it "has mojo" and that it's worth keeping. I can understand a few of those voters disagreed on their own grounds of the context being "not enough" though.  The question-answer pair seems valuable.

Comment: I think a more egregious closure would be required to convince anyone there's a real problem...  This post and the uncertainty of its fate falls in the bounds of "normal noise" for me.

Comment: @rschwieb I'm glad you at least partially see why this is an example of what I'm talking about. It claims to have been losed for not enough context--I suppose that can be for not showing work, but I don't think these are homework questions. These feel more like people trying to grapple with difficulty material asking questions to clarify their undersatnding. I don't know if showing work is prerequisite, especially when many of the question askers might be brief due to English not being their first language.

Comment: @rschwieb Another example that was closed, and reopened, is this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4165089/elliptic-curves-classification-including-the-case-of-non-perfect-fields/ I'm not sure how this one can be accused of being a bad question.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Personally, I think that both examples you gave have reasonable context. I don't understand what's going on in the first one, but I think it states a result and then asks a question related to that result, which would be good enough for me. I don't know about limiting moderating, but I could definitely see a case for clarifying how much context is necessary, asking close-voters to be more judicious with tags they don't have as much experience in, etc. I also think that the fact that the questions were reopened is evidence the system is working, if not quite optimally.

Comment: @AlexYoucis That one is definitely too many questions in one post.  I'd agree it 'needs focus'.  Good questions are being asked, yes, but they do not all have to be delivered in laundry list.  it also makes it harder for people to answer the entire question. It looks to me like you two are addressing what's  in (3) but I can't quite tell if the one -or-two questions in (4) are being answered.  Part of the problem may be that the user also enumerated (1) even though it isn't a question, and (2) seems to just be another question thrown in distinct from the later ones.

Comment: @MichaelJesurum I think your suggestions are very reasonable! Thank you for making them. The restriction of moderation priveleges to people who have some level of familiarity with the tag is perhaps too harsh.

Comment: @rschwieb Unfortunately, therein lies the rub. I have a tendency to overwrite, and I think that if I was asked to 'provide more context' I might write something exactly like what that user wrote. Following **Michael Jesurum**'s suggestion, maybe a more reasonable course of action would be to more specifically address what constitutes the right level of context, especially concerning more advanced/niche topics. Thoughts? Thanks again for your input!

Comment: @AlexYoucis Context isn't an issue for the last one, right? It's clear this has enough context. What it doesn't have is a structure that makes it readable to others in the future.  That's why it was closed with "needs focus."

Comment: @AlexYoucis But defining context... that has been going on constantly over the past 5 years, at least. Most recently [EoQS](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) was discussed.  I don't think there are going to be major advances in redefining context levels...

Comment: @rschwieb I don't think there is that much of a difference. Legitimately (I'm really not just being argumentative) if you asked me to 'provide context' I would probably provide a) background, and b) related questions/concerns to help place it in the more general picture. It sounds like b) is what was taken issue with there.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Related questions are natural if they are either stronger or weaker formulations, but if they are just different variations in different directions I don't think they provide mutual context. Certainly they detract from focus.  Not that it would be a bad idea to link to dedicated questions, though!

Comment: By the way, if you want to make examples known to at least some users, but not everyone, I saw someone in a different SE.meta put the links in a deleted answer.  10K+ users will be able to see it

Comment: I consider myself a non-expert in many tags and to be explicit I don't have a masters or PhD in maths. With just a few courses in undergrad I have a limited scope and yet I have closed questions where I have no expertise. My primary motive for demanding context in questions is to help math enthusiasts (like myself) get interested in topics which are new for them. Questions with no context or motivation are just not helping non-experts.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Personally, I never vote to close questions above my level of competence. As a non-expert, I find it difficult to judge what constitutes a reasonable context or motivation. This is particularly difficult in the case of advanced topics such as Algebraic Geometry (of which, as an outsider to the field, I know fair amount, but not nearly enough to feel comfortable to close most questions). For most questions in AG , it would take a reader unfamiliar with the area about a year of serious reading to understand what the questions are about.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: well sometimes the questions look straight like a problem statement (PSQ). In those cases I tend to give a close vote. Otherwise there is always the option to skip and move to next review item.

Comment: "Questions with no context or motivation are just not helping non-experts." @Para, I don't think there's any rule saying that every question posted to m.se must help non-experts. If you look at the reasons you can choose among for voting to close a question, "this question doesn't help me" is not among them.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: well I use the reason "missing context or details". The point of my comment was that I don't like context less questions and I provided one reason why I don't like them.

Comment: @Para, it's fine not to like them, but you go beyond dislike when you vote to close. Please vote to close when a question deserves closing, not when you just don't like the question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I don't see the point of arguing here. The vote to close is based on the policy related to context. And after so many debates there is no universal agreement here on what counts as sufficient context. So in a way close votes have an element of subjective-ness.

Comment: There are area of mathematics that just bounce off my brain every time I've looked at them. Alg Geom is one of them. I am totally happy for alg. geom. questions to be fairly impenetrable to me, and alg. geom. discussers shouldn't have to bring me up to speed with every question they ask.

Comment: "there is no universal agreement here on what counts as sufficient context." @Para, agreed. But I think you're the first one to put "helps me to get interested in a new topic" as a necessary condition for sufficient context.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: if something motivates people to learn some new thing, I think that's something positive and worth striving for. I don't think there is anything wrong with such an attitude. There are other reasons for context (say to prevent cheating on assignments), but I somehow feel this aspect related to learning to be more important for me. However I must say that reviewers should avoid being trigger happy and in case of any doubt should skip rather than close. More so when they are non-experts.

Comment: "if something motivates people to learn some new thing, I think that's something positive and worth striving for." @Para, of course, but you aren't distinguishing what's necessary from what's sufficient.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Just because you can't understand a question, that does not mean it is a bad question. It may lack context to you, but for others who know, I would be clear what the problem is about. I would not close questions about algebraic geometry, or hard nonlinear PDEs. This community is for all kinds of levels of mathematics, If a question if out of your understanding , just move on and ignore it. If you have some curiosity,  ask the OP or who ever answers to the OP. I seem to remember that it is encourage to skip closing questions (specially when the OP is out of our breadth).

Comment: @OliverDiaz: if the question is a PSQ then it should be closed. The problem arises when some minimal is available. A non-expert may not be able to judge the quality of question in this case and then it is better to skip it.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: agree, but just ask yourself, are you well qualified to judge a particular question, even  if it is out out your breadth. You may not be able to get the contact from looking at the question, to others, the question is very clear. You may suggest someone else to take a look, but don't act as an executioner just because you don't understand the topic or the problem.

Comment: @OliverDiaz: the judgement of a question with regard to context is not exactly the same as judging its mathematical merit, challenge factor or interesting nature. The former does not require the same level or kind of expertise as the latter and the closing/reopening of questions is primarily based on former. And I reiterate that in case of doubt the best option is to skip.

Comment: I could get behind having a separate discussion/brainstorming session about how to give sufficient "context" to an advanced question. But [my attempt at such brainstorming in the case of contest questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32223/11619) was a failure in the sense that nothing much was unearthed. I am linking that thread mostly because some objections to contest questions getting a different treatment (or having separate pieces of advice) were raised there. And they may also apply here.

Comment: We could still try that, and collect the fruits of that labor to an extra answer in the [How to ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619).  [Like this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/32403/11619). Nevertheless, in my opinion, the pragmatic thing to do on this site is not to place any extra obstacles to reviewing, and move to fix the imperfections. I exercise extreme caution when reviewing questions from an area I am totally unfamiliar with. Many (but not all) active reviewers follow a similar policy, and the process converges fast enough.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen (1) I think that you raise an interesting point here:  there are standards for quality on this site, but every "type" of question seems to have some contingent which believes that the standards should not apply to that type of question.  I have heard that elementary questions shouldn't require context because neophytes cannot be asked to write clear mathematics (they lack the mathematical maturity).  In this case, we are being told that advanced questions don't require context, as anyone who actually matters may discern the context without further prompting.

Comment: (2) As you point out, there are also arguments as to why contest questions may not require context (or, at least, should have different standards applied to them).  So, I guess, my question is the following:  if context standards shouldn't apply to low-level questions, or to high-level questions, or to contest questions, where **do** the context standards apply?

Comment: (3) Personally, my understanding is that there are quality standards on this site, and that they exist for various reasons (to make the database searchable, to help orient answerers, and, yes, to prevent cheating, among other things), and that they should be applied uniformly.  Low-level questions require context.  High-level questions require context (at the very least, a non-expert should be able to tell the difference between a question which may be interesting to an expert from a question which is not).  Contest questions require context.  *Every* question needs context.

Comment: Well explained @XanderHenderson. We are back to "pragmatic". And "compromise". The goal was, perhaps, to discuss what kind of context would be most beneficial for different types of questions. My experience was that we couldn't find much difference between low-level questions and contest questions. And I predict that the outcome of a similar brainstorming here would not bring up anything really new either. In other words, I'm not gonna initiate such a brainstorming thread again, but if somebody who feels more strongly about it wants one, I will try to contribute.

Comment: (cont'd) Such an exercise may appease a few users. Then it has served a point :-/

Comment: @AlexYoucis " every finite-dimensional k-algebra is Artinian" is it commutative? I think that's not clear and with some frequency an issue of confusion. Many a user works in a *context* where the default is commutative so much so that they won't say it. Other's don't and it's clear that if it is not said it's commutative then it is not to be assume.

Comment: @AsafKaragila "where in fact anyone who can understand it anyway already knows the whole context" yes! yes yes yes yes yes i bugs me when people whine about context and motivation when the context and motivation are abundantly clear from the question. Not that I know what to do about it, the suggestion in the "question" seems like a bad of many worms...

Comment: Here's a recent example. I received 3 close votes on my question. I've used math.SE for 9 years and was surprised, so this is a new development -- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4189444/solving-for-s-in-e1-hs-in-terms-of-moments-of-h

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I know it's on completely different topics and it's hard to compare, but the first version of your post has absolutely no context/motivation, while the two links by Alex have at least some. Also, it's not known if the close-voters of your post are  "non-expert" (Now that your post had been edited, I guess we might never know who voted).

Comment: @ArcticChar I'm not criticizing this development, just saying this is new, and unexpected for users who don't keep up with Meta. In my last 96+ questions I have usually received good answers without being asked to provide additional motivation

Comment: Yes, I agree that after [EoQS](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards), it seems more users join force in enforcing the quality control. @YaroslavBulatov

Comment: @ArcticChar aha, that's the key post, thanks for the context!

Comment: Some related discussions on [meta.se]: 
[Question closed by votes from people who do not appear to be familiar with the topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240737) and
[Should closing as “too localized” require knowledge of the question's area?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147995)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: I checked the only answer in your 1st link. It starts with the premise "Nobody needs technical knowledge to know a question is hard to understand: all they need to do is have trouble understanding it." This is surely true in many areas but is utterly false in advanced areas of math. (But, of course, sometimes one can infer that a question is badly written simply from poor formatting or English.) It's just an example of how different MSE (and MO) are from other SE's, so general SE suggestions do not always apply to math.

Comment: Today I stumbled upon another post on this meta: [Should members of the forum be able to delete answers in a topic that is outside of their field?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32928) It is about deleting rather than closing - but perhaps the discussion there can be seen as somewhat related to this question.

Answer (score 21):

The first obvious issue (which I feel is what may have triggered this post, and has been identified by other users in the comments) is that experts can guess the context from a question, and appreciate why it is relevant, even if there is *zero* detail given in the original post. They may also know most of the background and guess what the motivation behind asking the question is. As such, some questions seem perfectly reasonable for them, that non-experts will find not up to [standard](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). From this point of view, the frustration you expressed is completely understandable. However, we definitely cannot (and will not) ask people not to help us moderate certain posts of the site simply because they are not experts on a particular topic.

On the other hand, one can draw a parallel between this situation and writing a paper for a non-specialized or general journal: if your audience is wide, then an extra dose of context and background may be necessary for your article to be appropriate for the journal. You may find yourself defining certain terms that may be very common in your subfield of expertise, and reminding the reader of previous work that is absolutely well-known in your area, but that is the trade-off we need to make to reach our desired audience.

In some way, posting a question on the site follows this idea: the background and expertise of our user base is very, very varied, and the volume of questions we get every day is constantly increasing. As such, many users that  may not be experts in an area will still be helping our [efforts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1) to tackle low-quality posts. The issue arises: do low-quality questions on relatively advanced topics (for example, schemes) deserve the same treatment as low-quality questions on pre-calculus and algebra?

I believe that we can meet half-ways: any post in the site indubitably benefits from context, background, and a show of effort from the OP, and there seems to be no strong argument to change our standards for advanced questions. At the same time, maybe for these, we can be slightly more relaxed as to *how far* we want to take this. For example, someone may be trying to compute the first or second page of a spectral sequence, and requiring them to show their full attempt may be counterproductive.

Comment: I agree that some quality control is needed to weed out the "do my homework" questions (which seems to be the whole purpose of many curators), the nonsensical questions,  and the reasonable questions. What I have observed, is that some curators are forming cliques and close questions just because someone member of the clique requested it. Often, the question may be out of their breadth, but they still close it because... well they are part of a clique. That is more harmful to this site in my opinion.

Comment: @OliverDiaz I agree that users forming cliques to *arbitrarily* close questions is a problem (perhaps similar to a vote ring, maybe worse). We do keep an eye on such cliques, and try to make sure that close reasons are always within site policy. You can always flag posts that you think have been arbitrarily closed for us to look at.

Comment: @OliverDiaz I guess you are probably alluding to CURED as a clique but this is an incorrect usage of the word. Part of the definition implies members exclude non-members; however, the opposite is true of CURED.  Everyone is welcome to introduce ideas to close, undelete, reopen, edit or delete.  Welcome under the standard rules governing chats, that is.  So, I hope readers realize the connotation of the term "clique" is not warranted.  A more neutral word like "group" would have sufficed.

Comment: Most  people at CURED that are doing a fantastic job, but a few visitors there who use are quick executioners (as opposed to quick guns) and do closed just because someone else ask for it, instead of looking at the posting, think abut whether they understand the question, and take a thoughtful decision. I call them clique because, when you agree with them on all is ticket boo, but when you descent, useless byzantine discussions ensue that often become out of order. I myself have allowed been baited into this type of discussions. But ok, call them groups, factions, gangs, clubs, parties, etc.

Comment: @OliverDiaz I have long advocated for a "quick to close, slow to delete" mentality.  Closure is not a punishment, and need not be permanent.  It is a signal to the asker that improvement is required, and a signal to potential answerers that the question should not be answered in its current form.  You phrase this as "execution", however, which is incredibly loaded.  You have also already been criticized for referring to "cliques".  It seems that you are trying to create a kind of us-vs-them narrative, and cast the opposition as "the enemy".

Comment: May I suggest that you seek to avoid such incendiary language?

Comment: Hm, I interpreted cliques in a very mathematical way. I would also suggest to avoid "executioners", etc.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: There are certainly some "groups" that go fishing to find whatever they feel is PSQt. You have your own opinions on context, and certainly I do not share that rigid view for questions that are not the typical homework question. Closing a question unilaterally  when the community opted for a reopen is questionable. You were elected democratically as a moderator, but you have to be fair and accept it when questions are reopened. Unless you found evidence that a question is being used for cheating purposes )contest, exams, etc).

Comment: @OliverDiaz When I encountered that question, I saw a PSQ with a long, acrimonious thread in which the author attacked users asking for improvement.  I deleted the comments and closed the question as a PSQ.  I did not investigate the timeline of the question, and did not notice that it had previously been closed (though this likely would not have changed my actions).  If moderators were here only to enact the will of the largest plurality of community members, we would not be given the ability to unilaterally close questions.

Answer (score 17):

No question in mathematics is unmotivated or intrinsically interesting.  Despite the fact that I, myself, often use the phrase "this is a natural question," no question in mathematics is actually natural.  A question *becomes* interesting or natural once one has enough of a background to appreciate where a question comes from.

For example, I think that the following is an extremely natural question to ask:

> Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ be a metric space, and $f: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ an $\alpha$-Hölder map.  Is it true that
> $$ \operatorname{dim}_{\text{As}}(f(X)) \le 
> \frac{\operatorname{dim}_{\text{As}}(X) - 1}{\alpha},$$
> where $\operatorname{dim}_{\text{As}}(X)$ denotes the Assouad dimension of $X$?<sup>[1]</sup>

Anyone who can answer the question likely already knows what all of these terms mean, and why the question is interesting, and so on.  It is likely an "intrinsically interesting" question to experts.  That doesn't make it a good question on Math SE.

Off the top of my head, this question would be much improved by

1. Providing a reference for basic definitions—in particular, the Assouad dimension is, maybe, not the most familiar object.  A citation to an appropriate paper in which the dimension is defined would be incredibly helpful.  An actual definition would be even better, but is maybe not required.
2. A similar result holds for the Hausdorff dimension.  Why not mention that?
3. This question was posed to me by a colleague, so I don't actually know what motivated him to ask, but, given his research area, I have strong suspicions.  Why not explain that?  "This question is related to controlling the behaviour of differential operators near the boundaries of John domains."
4. I haven't really spent much time on this question, but if I were to post it here, I would almost certainly have put some effort into it.  Explaining where the wheels fell of would be helpful.  For example: "Paralleling the argument for the Hausdorff dimension in [reference], it seems that we should be able to make an estimate of the form [foo], but the inequalities end up going in the wrong direction at step [bar]."

I will also point out that this kind of question can serve to **advertise** the topic being studied.  If you phrase a question so that *only* experts are going to understand it, then you are only reaching experts.  On the other hand, if you phrase a question so that even a non-expert might understand where it comes from, you might convince the non-expert that the question or field of study is interesting, and put someone on a path towards expanding your area of expertise.  Maybe you are one of those paranoid academics who is obsessed with priority and deeply fearful of getting scooped but, if not, isn't a Good Thing™ to attempt to be more inclusive an bring more people into the fold?

Even if a question is more advanced, context is required.  Rather than chaffing against this requirement, why not think of it as an opportunity to spread the word about something you find interesting?

---

[1] As an aside, if anyone has an answer to that question, I would be mildly interested to see it—a similar question was posed to me by a colleague, and I had to reply with a shrug of the shoulders.  One of these days, I'll sit down and see what's what, but haven't had time to think about it for a while.

Comment: You seem to suggest that to post a question you have to go through a list of checks. A question does not have to be over 100 characters to be a good question (whether its a precalculus question or a Malliavin Calculus question). To some members, the question will be clear, to others not. But if a curator has no idea about the question (its a topic they don't grasp, for example) they should not behave as executioners for the sole reason of not understanding the nature of the  OP.  A big problem I found enforcement lately is that curators are forming cliques according to their guts.

Comment: My personal take on the question Assouad dimension that you wrote is that it is good question, completely appropriate for MSE and if I saw it I would never vote to close it but would suggest asker to pose it on MO within a week if there is no MSE answer. But that's just me.

Comment: @OliverDiaz (1) Every question is required to provide context.  Period.  I am sorry if this feels arbitrary or silly, but it is a requirement of this site.  A 100 character problem statement may very possibly be a good question in an abstract sense, but it is *not* a good question for Math SE.  "Clarity" is only one part of what makes a question of sufficient quality for inclusion here.  Searchability and focus are *also* important (where focus can have something to do with circumscribing the intended audience, and warning off others).

Comment: (2) If an author has not sufficiently explained that a question is likely to be beyond the ken of most users, then they have failed to provide sufficient context for the question.  If non-experts are not even given enough information to distinguish a high level question in a specialized field from an example or exercise in a textbook, the asker has failed to provide sufficient context.  In these situations, non-experts can very reasonably vote-to-close.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I very strongly disagree.  If I were to see that question---despite being somewhat expert in the area and understanding what might motivate it---I would unilaterally close it.  Problem statement questions are not appropriate questions for Math SE, no matter what the level of the question.

Comment: It is easy to see whether a question is missing context, or if the context is sifficient, when you are expert in that area. I dont think the OP is asking that. The question for the reviewers is: should they vote to close a question in an area where they know nothing about, even if the question looks like a PSQ.

Comment: @ArcticChar We have source, background, definitions, attempt, motivation. Of these things, I imagine a source is discernible for anybody wishing to check for it. For example, "I was doing the following calculation [link to post/textbook link etc.] when I hit upon question ...". would count as an explicit mention of the source. So that's a big plus point. An attempt is usually easy to spot, I tried/did ... . What might be missed is the link between different statements, and how one statement motivates or forms a background for the question. Another miss is "how much effort is enough?" which...

Comment: ... means that if there's nothing in the question apart from a problem statement, then everybody can make it out, but the minute we have small little statements like : "So ... is true for XYZ functions. What do we know about it being true for ABC functions?" then only an expert can provide weightage on how significant the first statement is towards motivating or being a background for the second. Ideally, though : a source goes a long, long way in an expert question, and linking similar(possibly easier questions) questions is an absolute win-win for all.

Comment: In short, the only part where people may be requiring expert advice is on how much other statements in the question post motivate/form a background for the main question. The rest of the criteria, I believe, does not require any kind of guesswork or faith-jumping to be judged. Another thing is that I wouldn't be ashamed if I was a low-level user, to write on a high level question and ask for elaboration of certain parts. That would definitely be the most helpful thing to do : if in the process I'm able to read up something about the subject, it makes it even nicer, and the question gets better

Comment: I agree with everything you said, but I am asking exactly the boardline case you described: where an advanced question looks **almost** like a PSQ (but it's not). This is also the case which motivates this question (see the [first link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4183836/proper-morphism-and-base-change)). @TeresaLisbon

Comment: Or just take the example here. If the definition of Assouad dimension is included (as a link), I am already not sure if **sufficient** context is given.

Comment: @ArcticChar You have me trussed up! For starters, I would request for sources on both questions : for either the motivating statements, or the question itself, or a general reference. This much would be enough for the question which you linked, along with maybe one line about what's different about proving the properness of the map $X_k \to Spec(K)$ versus $X_k \to X$ (that is not necessary for me , it's only for someone who requests it but it links the first statement and the question better). For Xander's question, a singular source (like a textbook) is enough : but only the definition of ..

Comment: .. Assouad dimension would not be enough, because that's just a definition in addition to a problem statement. See, this is my IDEAL cheatsheet for advanced problems : I think a source (even if self-made : then you mention that) just has to be there. Then you should have ONE of motivation (i.e. another statement + link to this statement) , OR background (I'm looking to interpret this from a ... background / I'm reading from ... book as well where) OR similar questions (I saw a similar question here, but the approach here doesn't work etc.) , and then problem statement. That's good!

Comment: So basically, state your problem. Then state how you came up with it (found it somewhere, got inspired by something). Then state one or more statements or questions that is linked to this line, and link those statements/questions with the question you want to ask. If you feel the need, state the definitions of ambiguous terms. Now, the only thing that an expert will need to interpret is if that link is obvious enough, or needs to be emphasised. I am ok if the question of Hajar Hajar is not closed, but if Xander posted his problem and only gave a definition of the Assouad dimension, close.

Comment: @ArcticChar "It is easy to see whether a question is missing context, or if the context is sifficient, when you are expert in that area."  That is exactly my point.  Math SE is not for experts---it is for *everyone*.  If a reviewer cannot read a question and distinguish between an interesting expert-level question and a homework problem in a field they are unfamiliar with, then the asker has failed to provide sufficient context, and the reviewer *should* vote to close.

Comment: For me, #2 seems the most relevant, followed by something like #3, and for #3 it's probably enough to simply said a positive answer would help with XXX topic being investigated (or perhaps just wondering whether the answer was known because they were thinking of working on it). What tends to irk me the most are problems that *seem* like they're a contest-type problem, but just as well could be a naively made up problem (e.g. can $x^{y^x}$ be rational if $x$ and $y$ are both rational and not integers?) that might be totally intractable (unlike a contest or book problem).

Comment: Incidentally, I have no idea how difficult the made-up problem I posed in my last comment might be, which was my point -- I just made it up and didn't invest any time into trying to solve it, and it's difficult to see the motivation for it in the sense that I could easily make up several others like this. It would help others to know whether the problem was a book/class/contest problem or simply made up, since at least if the former we know we're not trying to possibly solve a Hilbert level problem such as whether $2^{\sqrt 2}$ is algebraic.

Comment: @Dave, $x=1/4$, $y=1/16$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Did you have any time to look at the stated problem? I had to do some recent reading on fractal geometry and happened to recall this question.

Answer (score 17):

Here is a thought. If you, an expert in a topic, see a problem-statement-question that is interesting, and if you know this question is not a duplicate, and if you judge that adding some context would increase the value of the question to MSE (in part by increasing the chance that someone would be willing to write a good answer before those pesky non-experts vote to close it), then edit the question lightly to include enough context to avoid it being closed.

I have seen this done in the comments sometimes, in fact I have done it myself in the comments, for example by adding a link to a definition which I know is important but perhaps not commonly understood.

Comment: In the comments, perfect. Editing the question to do it should , in my opinion, be done with the permission of OP (so first drop a comment and then have OP lift it, or lift it yourself) and is best done by the OP themselves. But editing, either by OP or by someone interested, achieves the better end result (compared to context in comments) as far as curation is concerned : it's a win-win if the OP is willing to improve their question and allow others to help format their question.

Comment: I have been advocating something like this, but cannot boast a good track record here. The moderators spent quite a long time thinking about it, and posted [this guideline](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32402/11619). If editing can be done within the guideline, then it's fine I think.

Comment: Also, this is why users with a gold badge on a topic can close the questions in that topic with a single vote and also reopen them as needed.

Comment: @NikhilKumarSingh that applies only to duplicate closure and reopening.

Comment: -1: the closing brigade is not known to go back and reopen questions they have closed. So one had to go and make an explicit post in the "reopen" thread. But that's a one-by-one solution that requires significant effort, compared to the mindless clicks of the closers.

Comment: I don't really follow what you are saying, @MartinArgerami, my suggestion is not aimed at those who are inclined to vote to close (your "closing brigade"?). My suggestion is instead aimed at those who see a question that is not yet closed, is in danger of being closed, and has some evident room for improvement.

Answer (score 7):

This is really a double-edged sword.

I agree that it is frustrating to see good posts being closed, especially when the close-voters don't seem to have the background to understand the given contexts (even when explicitly given in the post).

However, it is equally frustrating to see low quality/no context posts not being closed. This could happen if the power of the close-voters are further restricted. From my experience (unfortunately I don't have statistics to support that), it is far more difficult to close a Riemannian geometry question then a post in e.g. Calculus or Linear algebra.
My guess is that close-votes reviewer are in general less willing to vote on advanced topics (e.g. see [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33794/non-experts-closing-questions#comment155131_33794) comment).

Also, the suggested proposal is quite absurd, since more knowledgeable users would be banned from some closing some elementary questions. e.g. I am then not allowed to vote to close questions in [elementary-set-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-set-theory) (which I never answered), or even [algebra-precalculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus) (only 2 answers).

I fully agree with Asaf that there is no simple solution to this. As suggested (by Asaf), what one could do is to

- leave a comment below and describe how that is a good questions while the post is not yet closed, and
- vote to reopen when it's closed. Use the [Reopen thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32975/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-01-2021-today) when necessary.

Comment: I agree with you and Asaf. There are instances however, when questions are reopened, some curators (or a clique of curators who use the close option and some sort of punishing gadget) get up in arms put pressure on some moderators to re-close and/or delete, and a moderator unilaterally close the question again just to avoid confrontation.

Comment: @OliverDiaz The active reviewers do exchange links to questions links they find questionable in a chatroom dedicated for such activity. But I don't think there are "cliques". Most of the active users of that chatroom vote according to their personal criteria. It is a possibility that in borderline case some of us/them follow the opinion of a user who they think is qualified to judge a case. But most of that activity is directed to lower level questions. Simply because such questions are more numerous, and need a more urgent response.

Comment: (cont'd) Anyway, there have been complaints about the mode of operation of that chatroom, which is why moderators have kept an eye of the proceedings for many years now. To a casual visitor it probably looks worse than it is. If only due to the telegraphic style of the chat message (lists of links), and occasional rants due to frustration. I think the volume of traffic there has been going down lately. Possibly due to EoQS, but it is probably too soon to tell. It is also possible that this impression of mine is inaccurate as I haven't had the time to check it out lately.

Answer (score 5):

My experiences with having questions closed is that it can be arbitrary, with too much authority given to individuals whose rankings are sufficiently high to be able to cause a question to be closed.

Perhaps annotation flagging problems with questions could be extended such that if enough time goes on without raised issues being corrected, possibly combined with an assessment that the question has generated insufficient interest, the question is closed. Then it would be algorithmic, and less subject to what frankly feels like somebody's whim at times on this site.

One good test of a question's worthiness is if it generates any serious interest. If a question has been closed which in fact had generated interest, then the interests of some users are not being met.

In fact I reached this thread because I was looking at a geometry question I had bookmarked - only to find it had been closed: [Prove that the 4 points are concyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4187574/prove-that-the-4-points-are-concyclic). While I agreed that the asker of this question could have provided more detail about their efforts, I also thought, for example in this particular case, that the person who asked the question had put considerable effort into the diagram provided.

Also, I have had several questions of my own closed that I know I put a great deal of effort into making as clear and precise as I was able, and that generated some interest prior to being closed.