# Are we closing short questions too hastily?

Tags: discussion, closing, closed-questions

I refer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4694040), which I was spending a couple hours preparing the answer for only to find it already closed by the time I could post it.
This is not the only instance in recent memory – I managed to post an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4689150) before it was closed.

I note that there are four closers in common between the two questions, and none of them seem to have any relevant expertise.
It would be nice if we could easily reopen wrongly closed questions, but even as a gold badge holder in the relevant tag it seems my reopen vote carries no extra weight (unlike for duplicate votes).

Comment: With regards to your last sentence, do you mean if we had [a dedicated meta thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34447/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-01-2022-today) where you, as an expert, can raise awareness that a question being telegraphic is not necessarily the same as it being without context and ask people to vote to reopen it?

Comment: Related: [non-experts-closing-questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33794/non-experts-closing-questions)

Comment: I think there is a problem of closing questions too hastily, not only for short questions. Too many hasty closers, often without a sufficient expertise. It happend to me that I answered a question, that was hastiliy closed, in my opinion wrongly, and I lost my upvotes, but this is not the problem. What annoyed me was  that among  the closers there was a user that didn't even know the difference beetween a bijection and an injective function,  a high reputation user was trying to explain this difference to  this user in the comments.  This user after a minute  voted to close the question.

Comment: @Baker, you may lose upvotes when a question is deleted, but I don't think you lose them when a question is closed.

Comment: @ Gerry Myerson
Yes yes, you are right, it was closed **and** deleted, after a curious mess by closers and the OP, after few minutes.

Comment: Maybe we should make a proposal where people with a silver badge or higher on a particular tag can vote to close questions with that tag and have at least 3,000 reputation points. I find it strange how a person could just get 3,000 reputation points by answering just trigonometry questions and gain the privilege to close questions on more advanced topics like differential geometry. (I was thinking about this stuff a week ago, which is why I haven't been active in close-voting questions.)

Comment: I am neutral regarding suggestions to restrict close votes. If it were easier to _undo_ closures it would not necessarily be a problem if some questions are closed too hastily.

Comment: @ZhenLin I don't think the closures are *hasty* : they were done keeping standards in mind that are not the same as yours, that is all. Can you provide an argument that the first question, for example, doesn't lack context? It was closed for that. It talks about categories having some properties, but doesn't give an example of such a category. It also doesn't talk about where and why the author wants to know about such categories or came across them. That could easily be enough to see a question closed.

Comment: Examples are obvious to anyone who knows even a small amount of category theory. For example, any groupoid, or any preorder category.

Comment: That doesn't take away from the fact that these details are not present in the question. It's the same problem : something that appears "natural/obvious" to an expert isn't obvious to someone else. I can ignore that and skip these kinds of questions in a review queue : and have been doing so for some time. But I don't expect others to abide by that. Anyway, you can see [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/33810/316409) and [this comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33794/non-experts-closing-questions?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment155253_33801).

Comment: I simply do not believe context is needed for such questions. If someone asks, “what is a matrix whose square is itself called?” without bothering to give examples, would you close it instead of actually just writing the answer?

Comment: Then we differ in our respective outlooks. Yes, I'd vote to close such a question. If, however,  I were sufficiently interested in it and it were also not a duplicate, I'd edit in examples such as scalar multiples of the identity. I cannot identify the source of such a question. Alternately, I'd ask a fresh question with better context, answer it myself and closed the existing question as a duplicate. Why do you believe that context is not needed? You're not the only one interacting with the question : future visitors are the large number, and many of them won't be interested, the way you are.

Comment: Anyway, I should probably not wade into opinions that I don't own fully (and it's been hashed out here before) so I'll drop this conversation, but these are not open-and-shut cases, and pretty much every party has a case here. I do agree on one thing, though : tag badge holders should have stronger moderation powers in their tag.

Comment: Context is not needed because it is a simple question. There is no need for questions to be interesting to everyone – it just needs to be interesting to people who have the same question and people who could provide an answer. Full disclosure: I do not think the first linked question is by any means a _good_ question. In fact, it seems I answered the same question [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4385253/5191) and forgot about it. I would not object to closing low-effort questions as duplicates. But we should answer these questions at least once so that the answer can be googled!

Comment: I think this is a part of bigger problem, quality of moderation.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer is completely missing the point with "something that appears "natural/obvious" to an expert isn't obvious to someone else". You don't need to be an expert in category theory to know the most basic examples of groupoid, and so on. You could even be an amateur and know this. Expert is 100% not required - I have complained on many closed questions that are excellent questions, but closed by some gold rep players completely unnecessarily.

Comment: @Snared I guess the term "expert" in the context of MSE is understood as users who process the corresponding knowledge, so that they can answer most of the questions in that tag. Whether or not they are amateur is not crucial.

Comment: @Snared I am not an amateur but I don't know what a groupoid is. I agree that tag badge holders should have higher moderation abilities in their own tag and stated the same. I'll come down another rung : expert is not 100 percent required, but without a shadow of a doubt experts can appreciate and intuit the reason behind questions, quicker than an amateur. I would still like an argument as to how the first question here is an "excellent" question from you. If you are setting the bar too low, then you will have to talk to people who set it higher.

Comment: Also, I don't know where you make your complain about questions closed incorrectly. But the correct/most efficient way to file your complain is to write an answer to the [dedicated meta thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34447/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-01-2022-today) to get it reopened, as suggested in the first comment in this thread. @Snared

Comment: Once again, let me make it clear : there is no issue vis-a-vis the time of closure : it's that we have actively different standards. Let's talk, though. Ok, so I'm of the opinion that a lot of people who visit these questions should not be expected to know category theory, and that the question should be made to cater to them : the question should be made to be interesting and attractive to even those that are outside of the subject. It can be of use : I learn a lot from questions in topics I don't even know because of links, and plenty of information. That influences moderation.

Comment: Sure, I can choose to not close such questions (and do that, actually). Only give experts charge of higher moderation powers such as close/reopen/edit (other than trivial edits) on "expert" tags. We can try and run a poll on that and see how it fares, if only to hear more arguments.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer When you say you're not an amateur in category theory, do you mean you know nothing or you are stronger than an amateur? If you mean stronger, how do you not know of a groupoid, just curious? That seems like an extremely natural object to consider once first learning category theory. Your comment makes sense if by not an amateur you meant "Not even an amateur" - meaning knowing next to no category theory

Comment: @Snared Sorry, just confirming : I'm not an amateur *mathematician*. Yes, I read a bit of category theory from a book and know what morphisms and monomorphisms are, but I don't know of an example of what the 1st qn. states and while it "sounds natural"(definitely), it lacks context. I don't know what a groupoid is. I only read category theory for fun and never went beyond some result that stated that every category looks like one with sets and functions. Nevertheless : I just want to say that questions should make efforts to be accessible to a larger audience.

Comment: (I forgot the name of the book : I'll retrieve it if you need it. It covered the definitions, some basic examples, and then the theorem. The groupoid wasn't among the examples).

Comment: For some people, I’m sorry but I get the impression that closing questions is their main hobby in life. With a newcomer, there ought to be a very explicit indication of what needs to be rectified in this particular case, and an indication that if it’s not fixed in e.g. 3 days, the question will be closed

Comment: I agree with OP and tend to believe that short questions tend to be unfairly closed. For instance, [this question about the Weierstrass function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4675215/) is a typical example of a (imo) good question which is quite natural and well motivated by the OP, but was still closed as "missing context". Yes, maybe the OP could have added *more* context in different ways, but to most people who studied a bit of real analysis, I think the question is perfectly fine as it stands.

Comment: @StratosFair To broaden the class of people who can understand and appreciate the motivation behind that question, I added some links and reworded the question. . The context thus given was inadequate , in my opinion, only because it failed to pique the interests of those not familiar with the subject. Editing such questions with adequate links (which is allowed) can be done and is what I did. In no time, it has 4 reopen votes.

Comment: In my opinion people not familiar with the subject _have no business_ voting to close. This is not a competition for space or attention. By all means, downvote bad questions – after all, downvoting is not a free action, so I think users would think twice before doing so, and downvoting is easy to counteract.

Comment: @Sarvesh, thank you for the edit, it indeed improves the question by quite a lot  and indeed makes it accessible to a broader audience. However, I disagree with you that context was "inadequate" simply because "it failed to pique the interest of people not familiar with the subject". In my understanding, MSE is supposed to be a repository of high quality Q&A, and a "high quality question" is not necessarily a "question that can be understood by or interesting for everyone".

Comment: I believe actually that the audience of a question should be all people studying or familiar with the underlying subject in the broad sense (i.e. the tags of the question), and certainly not "as many people as possible" (which trying to make *all* questions interesting to even those unfamiliar to the subject would suggest). If the question is clear, well motivated, and helpful for those interested in the topic in the topic, then there is enough context. Having to define every single term so that people unfamiliar with the topic can understand what is going on can create unnecessary clutter...

Comment: @StratosFair There needs to be a balance, but I get what you say in your second comment above : there is a "right" level of audience that will appreciate the question. Anything below and the OP doesn't do enough to motivate the question. Anything more and the question's value is diluted by spurious details. It takes thought to hit the "right" audience, but questioners have to make an effort for this to be done. An element of quality is the ability to pique an audience's interest. I don't think the questions here, or the question which I edited, hit the right audience.

Comment: ... and ultimately makes it harder to understand what the main point of the question is. Also I think there is a tacit understanding that when an OP asks a (well motivated !) technical question where some specific terms are not defined, it's because there is a level of knowledge/expertise required to understand/answer the question in the first place that the people who don't know these terms are less likely to have. Ultimately my point is : if you see a question in a field you don't know containing some jargon you don't understand, don't vote to close it only based on that.

Comment: @StratosFair Although I don't feel as strongly about closure of such questions as the OP of this question, I agree and have been abiding by the non-closure protocol for questions in tags outside my expertise for a long time. I think I mentioned this in a comment earlier, but with enough consensus one can try to push through a meta post specifying non-closure in "non-expert tags" as an informal policy (I don't think there is a way in which one can measure how much of an "expert" one is in a field, unfortunately. Badges don't tell the full story).

Comment: Closing questions is sort of like honking the horn in a car. It can be necessary, but it is also creates an ugly atmosphere, not just for the person whose question is closed, but also for "passerbys" like myself and many other people in this thread. It is like walking into a city and people are honking their horns all over the place. Even if they are not honking at you, it is still generally bad vibes. After a while you don't want to visit there as much. I don't think rapid fire close voters realize how much damage they are doing by creating this culture.

Answer (score 18):

Thanks for bringing that specific Question (your first example, about category theory) to my attention (it has now been reopened).  There is a dedicated thread for asking for reopen and related actions, see current [Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34447/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-01-2022-today?noredirect=1&lq=1).

I added the reference request tag to the specific Question.  While my criterion for context is de minimis for all such close actions, where a question concerns terminology or reference materials, this lowered bar is especially relevant.  After all an asker has to have a starting point from which to ask more detailed guidance.

Answer (score 15):

This is partially answering a related question (if by harsh, you mean closing a question "too soon"): Yes, shorter questions are subject to harsher judgement.

According to [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/review-low-quality), short questions and answers are recognized by the system’s quality checks to be "potentially low quality", and will enter the Low quality posts queue automatically. Reviewers with 3k+ can vote to close directly in the Low quality posts queue, and Reviewers with 2k-3k reps can flag and push the post into the close vote review queue.

Given that the close votes review queue are always in huge backlog (in the extreme case, some close vote reviews are never finished), shorter questions do got closed faster than longer questions (assuming that they have similar quality), since they enter different queues. I guess this is what happened to the first post you link: the [LQ reviews](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1956431) is finished within the first 3 hours. In your second post, it enters just the close-vote review and the post is closed only after 40 hours.

Comment: I don't really know if the first post is short enough to trigger its entry into the LQ review queue (some others might had flagged the post). I guess the threshold is not public.

Comment: so what is your conclusion? Did you say in your any that the current mechanism of handling queues is OK from your POV?

Comment: There's no conclusion here. I am really just answering partially a related question, @Alex. If you ask for my personal opinion: the current situation is okay, in the sense that most low quality questions are eventually closed.

Answer (score 7):

My understanding is that MSE is supposed to be a repository of *high quality* questions and answers about mathematics. What constitutes a *high quality* question is of course (to some extent) a matter of personal opinion, but according to mine, a question which meets most of the following criteria is definitely "high quality enough" and doesn't deserve to be closed :

- It is *clear* and *understandable* by most people who are familiar with the topic in the broad sense (i.e. the tags of the question). For instance [the question cited by the OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4694040) is perfectly clear to anyone who has studied/is studying category theory, but it's totally impenetrable to me as I know nothing about this topic. That latter point should **never** be a reason to close a question.
- It is *well motivated* by examples or some explanation of how the question came about (questions asking about terminology don't necessarily need to satisfy this by the way). For instance the question [Quantile function is the almost surely left inverse of CDF](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4285574) I answered a while ago arose naturally as the OP was reading a Wikipédia article about the quantile function. I believe that amount of context is sufficient in general.
- It is *useful* and/or *helpful* in the sense that either many students of that topic are likely to encounter a similar question at some point, or people generally interested in that topic are likely to gain valuable insights by answering this question and/or answering it themselves. Of course, this point is rather subjective and best evaluated by people who are familiar enough with the topic. I think that [How discontinuous can a derivative be?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112067/how-discontinuous-can-a-derivative-be) is a good example of such a question, which is relatively short and full of technical terms which are not defined. I suspect some people would have voted to close it if it was posted today by a low-rep user, however it (and its answer !) is one of the most valuable real analysis questions on this site
- It is an *original question* which hasn't been asked/answered before on this site. Not much explanation needed on this last point, but as an illustration consider the question [$L^p$ and $L^q$ space inclusion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66029/lp-and-lq-space-inclusion) : if it was asked for the first time today, I expect that it would be closed within 24 hours, however this is again an extremely valuable question for this site that should stay open and have an answer that we can reference to in the future.

As a rule of thumb, if 3 out of 4 of the above criteria are met, the question should not be closed. If you see an "edge case" and you're not sure whether you should vote to close or leave open, just **skip** that question and **do not vote to close it.** As a converse of the above list, I would say that any of the below reasons *alone* should **never** be ground for closing a question :

- The question is not understandable/interesting for people who are not familiar with the topic.
- The question doesn't include OP's attempt/thoughts on solving it.
- The question is too short (some one sentence questions are extremely helpful and valuable).

Of course, this is only my personal opinion, and juding by the conversation so far, it seems like we won't reach a community-wide consensus. My suggestion would thus be, for people who see an interesting question they are afraid will get closed, to try and "protect" the question with a comment along those lines

> **to potential close voters :** this may appear as a Problem Statement Question for those unfamiliar with [topic XXX], but it is in fact a valuable question because [reasons YYY] which, as far as I can tell, has not been asked here before. As others interested in [topic XXX] will most likely find this question useful, please **do not vote to close it**.

Of course editing the question to add more context, as Sarvesh Ravichandran Iyer did e.g. for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4675215/857384), is definitely the most effective way to have it remain open, but in my opinion it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: For your comment to the close-voters: it is not always easy to check if a question had been asked before, since there's 1.5m questions out there. So think twice before making that statement. Also, simply saying that it's a "very challenging/insightful/valuable question with no justification does not help. A more useful approach is suggested by Mosher [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/33810/629362)

Comment: @ArcticChar you are right that it is quite easy to miss duplicates of a given question, so some question should be exerted (if the question is found to be a duplicate, it can (and should) of course be closed for that reason anyway). Regarding your second point, you are right that it's not convincing to claim that the question is "useful" without justification, so I edited my answer accordingly. The point of leaving such a comment is mainly to dissuade people in review queue from voting to close simply because they (wrongly) perceived the question as missing context.

Comment: Of course, if done properly, it is almost always better to directly edit the question to add more context : it can make the problem clearer, more interesting, attract more audience and thus potentially better answers as well. Edits which improve the quality of questions should always be *encouraged*, however they should **not** be *necessary* for questions such as the one discussed in the OP to remain open. (again, this is only my opinion)

Comment: re "...a repository of high quality questions and answers..." refer to [@uhoh's lemma #1: Stack Exchange is a collaborative effort to generate **good answers to on-topic questions.**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377004/303080) The idea that we should close questions thereby blocking the entire community from an opportunity to post answers because the question post itself is not independently deemed to be of sufficient "high quality" is a myth. It's all about the answers. Unless it's really attracting bad answers, give folks a chance to answer.

Comment: "...and doesn't deserve to be closed..." We do not punish questions! They don't "deserve" or not "deserve" to be closed.

Comment: @uhoh I wholeheartedly agree with you, questions on MSE are meant to attract *high quality* answers (this is what I wrote in my post, but I only focused on questions, since we're discussing when it is appropriate to close them). Again, what is a *high quality answer* (or "good") answer is partly subjective, but I believe that if a question follows most of the bullet points I've listed above, then it will most likely attract "good" answers, as in answers that will be helpful to other people interested in that topic in the future. So, ultimately, I believe we are making the same point.

Answer (score 6):

Just a sort of mental guide I use to choose whether or not to recommend closing (feel free to edit) :

1. If a question contains things like "Prove", "Find", or "Solve", without the OP's work, context, etc., the question is better closed.
2. If it contains things like "I was reading ..." and "I do not understand how/why ...", and contains some work or ideas, then it looks ok. If it does not contain any work or ideas, then skip (if you don't know much about the topic) or use your judgement skills (if you know about the topic).
3. Questions asking for terminology need not be closed.
4. There are some questions which do not fall in Category 1 but appear to do so. As in, "The definition of so-and-so says we can't have $x=0$. However, when I plug in $x=0$, I get this. How to prove this does not follow the properties of so-and-so?". In such questions, better skip if you do not understand the terminology.

Comment: (+1) point 4 in particular should be emphasized in my opinion. These are the typical questions which fall in a "grey area" and get too hastily closed by people who didn't read/understand them carefullly and treat them as if they were plain Problem Statement Questions

Answer (score -2):

I personally am not but "We" perhaps yeah I have definitely seen many short questions closed even though they showed in their comments how the question was relevant, that they had thought about it some, and had a nice question. But yeah personally I don't have enough rep to close questions personally so No to that, but for "We" perhaps yeah I could see the closing on short questions happening a bit too hastily lately.

Comment: I meant to write this as a comment, but as I no longer have enough reputation to write comments, I will write this here as part of the discussion

Answer (score -3):

Yes we are closing questions too hastily in another sense.

I will not comment here on the speed with which the decision is reached.

Rather the speed of implementation is too quick. Instead, particularly for a newcomer, I think it does no harm to give a day or so warning to a poster that their question may be closed. This warning, rather than general boilerplate would indicate specific issues perceived with *this* question.

I also think there should be a stub "Context:" already appearing in the question template, so that newcomers understand that this should be supplied.

Comment: This defeats the entire point of closure - the question in that form cannot and should not be answered on Math SE, so answering is blocked, until such time as the community determines it has been brought up to the required standard.

Comment: Regarding the template, see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416322/feature-test-ask-wizard-for-new-users-trial-has-completed) for details about the Stack Overflow "Ask Wizard".

Comment: Thanks @SarveshRavichandranIyer. How did that experiment work out?

Comment: Thanks @Nij. Does this hammer approach actually work? What’s the data on the number of repairable questions which are repaired vs abandoned? (Ignoring ones which are obviously beyond hope - my interest is in questions that *can* very well be answered but some feel *should not*).

Comment: Some of the reopen/close data can be found in the moderator tool, available to users with sufficient rep. Some statistics: 40 questions were reopened this month (May 2023), while at least 40 questions were closed within the last 8 hours. The no. of closed post that is edited subsequently is harder to find, but from the history of the reopen review queue, that seems to be around 10 each day. And around 1/4 of them are reopened (I hope some ppl more capable in SEDE can find the data).

Comment: Thanks @ArcticChar that summary already gives some context

Comment: @Laska There were improvements, particularly for first time askers. I think the "Ask wizard" will make a difference on this website, but they're still developing it, apparently.

Comment: (+1) *In lower question-rate sites* (~10/day) this often happens naturally; someone posts a suggestion for improvement or a warning that it might be closable for reason X. Often within a day or so the OP responds, often by fixing the problem. It's common for unattended/unimproved questions to get closed days or weeks later. *However* at over 300 questions per day, it's *really hard* in practice to give authors of problematic questions a few extra days, and then the attention necessary to close. You are right in principe, but it may require some changes to SE's workings to make this workable.

Comment: @uhoh thanks for this. However the sheer volume also means that once a question is closed, it’s a real struggle to get it open again. If someone comes and browses historical questions, they do not see the kind of context present which some current members demand as a measure of what they term “quality”. And yet those questions were happily answered. So it’s very easy for new folk to end up posing a question which is immediately slam-dunk blocked. Bottom line: the sheer volume of questions which prevents proper follow-up is exactly why hair-trigger close is inapproapriate for newcomers’ posts

Comment: @Laska you are absolutely right about the problem. Definitely some new users are lost forever because of this. I think we're on the same page here.

Comment: No, that doesn't follow at all. If there is such a volume that each post will only be addressed once (not twice where it is closed and then reopened, or twice where it is commented and closed because nobody fixed it) then the decision must be in favour of what type the majority of such posts tend to be. If most posts were of okay quality despite needing improvements, then "default leave open and forget" would be viable. But they're not - the majority of posts relevant here are not appropriate, and they need to be put down fast, or forever sit amongst the sludge that they contribute to.